# Can we have to use Multi Select Picklist in Related Lookup Filter in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

Step 1: Master Object have Multi Select Pick List

Step 2: Detail Object have Pick-list

Expectation : When I click on Lookup button in Detail Object, it should compare the value selected in the detail Object with Values present in Master Object's Pick-list.

Note : I know It can't be done in customization using Related Lookup Filter, as Related Lookup Filter doesn't support having Multi Select Pick-list for comparison.

I expect something, like, When a User Clicks on Lookup Button, it should be able to compare the value selected in Detail Object with the value selected in Master Object's Pick-list to show the filtered result in the lookup window. How it needs to be added as a part of VF with Custom Controller.